# Proof that for all symmetric matrices $A$ and $B$, $AB=(BA)^T$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Recall that a matrix, $M$, is said to be symmetric if and only if $M=M^T$. I've been trying to use the homomorphic nature of the transpose operator to prove this proposition but this approach hasn't been working for me. I would think that this would be straightforward to prove (i.e., the proof wouldn't involve cracking out the definition of matrix multiplication) and suspect I'm just missing a really simple move here. Any and all insights are welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the well known fact $(BA)^{T}=A^{T}B^{T}$, and then the result is clear.

Comment: $*$Smacks forehead$*$

Comment: @Archaick:  I heard it from here! Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Since $A$ and $B$ are symmetric matrices, we know that $A = A^T$ and $B = B^T$. Recall that the transpose is "distributed" over a multiplication in the sense that $(XY)^T = Y^T X^T$.

Then we have
$$AB \\
= (A^T)(B^T) \\
= (BA)^T.$$